# How to implement a JPA AttributeConverter for handling NULL properly?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, null

I have written a JPA attribute converter to convert values between `java.lang.String` and `java.nio.Path`.

The converter works fine for non-null value. In case of converting `null` from the Java world to SQL, Hibernate inserts the string value `null` into the database row. But I would to have (SQL) `NULL`, so that the column is either empty or in case of NOT NULL contraint a constraint violation will be caused.

What do I wrong?

The converter looks like this:

```java
@Converter
public class PathConverter 
  implements AttributeConverter<Path, String> {
  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Path path) {
    return Objects.toString(path);
  }

  @Override
  public Path convertToEntityAttribute(String columnValue) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(columnValue)
                   .map(Paths::get).orElse(null);
  }
}
```

I am using Spring Boot 2.7.1 with Hibernate for my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Path path) {
   return Objects.toString(path);
}
```

To:

```
 public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Path path) {
    return path == null ? null : Objects.toString(path);
  }
```

because `Objects.toString()` return the string "null" if the value is `null`

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html):

> Returns the result of calling toString for a non-null argument and "null" for a null argument.

Comment: Yes, this works. For my case I changed `Objects.toString(path)` to `Objects.toString(path, null)`.